# How to access generator object from executor.map?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concurrent.futures

I have function that converts non numerical data in a dataframe to numerical.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from concurrent import futures

def convert_to_num(df):
  do stuff
  return df
```

I am wanting to use the futures library to speed up this task. This is how I am using the library:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    df_test = executor.map(convert_to_num,df_sample)
```

First I do not see the variable `df_test` being created and second when I run `df_test` in I get this message:

```
<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at >
```

What am I doing wrong to not be able to use the futures library? Can I only use this library to iterate values into a function versus passing a entire dataframe to be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map method for the executor object, as per the documentation, takes the following arguments,
`map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)`

From your example you only provide a single df (the df_sample) but you could provide a list of df_samples which are unpacked in as the iterables parameter.

For example,
Let us create a list of dataframes,

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

df_samples = [pd.DataFrame({f"col{j}{i}": [j,i] for i in range(1,5)}) for j in range(1,5)]
```

Which would look like, [df_samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KddH1.png)

And now we add a function which will add an additional column to a df,

```
def add_x_column(df):
    df['col_x'] = ['a', 'b']
    return df
```

and now use the ThreadPoolExecutor to apply this function to the df_samples list in a concurrent manner. You would also need to make convert the generator object to a list to access the changed df's

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(add_x_column, df_samples))
```

Where the results would be the list of the resultant df's

Where the results would look like, [df_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmzwx.png)